# Aptana Studio 3 - Content Assist

Tags: aptana, content-assist

Over the last few days this issue has been popping up and it's really beginning to annoy me as I spend more time correcting it than actually coding.

periodically when I am working with my JavaScript (jQuery) when I type `$` for say:
`$('#something').html` when I type `$` the content assist box comes up, which is fine but when I press `(` I get the following output:

```
$$()
```

instead of how it should look:

```
$()
```

Any idea's how to fix this without disabling content assist for JavaScript?  Thanks.

Comment: I have figured out the issue with this..  in Aptana Studio it has bindings for auto-inserting the proposed thing.  Whether this is $$ or $Array (the only two i've had it happen with) it is generally because you are typing ( when it happens.

To fix it, go to Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors -> Javascript and delete the insert proposed which by default is .( and that will fix the issue.  It fixed mine.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, It worked :D. BTW, why you don't answer your own question so I can vote it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment I have fixed this issue in 3.0.4 and before.  Aptana Studio has bindings for auto-inserting the proposed code.  To fix it, go to Windows -> preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Editors -> Javascript and delete the insert proposed which is by default: .( and that will fix your issue.

As Ingo Muschenetz states, 3.0.5 is supposed to have fixed this issue, but I have yet to actually try out that version to ensure that it does.

Comment: I've tried 3.0.5 of this software and it doesn't actually fix that issue.  it only removes the ( from the textbox to begin with, but if you happen to be doing something with a . it will still happen so this is the resolution for the issue in 3.0.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known bug and fixed in the update to 3.0.5: http://preview.appcelerator.com